# MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.RescueReceiveContextFilter<MassTransit.ReceiveContext> Error: 0 : Rescuing exception, System.NullReferenceException

Tags: masstransit

I'm sending group of 4 messages from client to server. On each message the server handle the data and respond back to client with `context.Respond`. 
Even though the client receives all 4 responses as expected, On the console window I can see few instances of the following:

> MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.RescueReceiveContextFilter
>   Error: 0 : Rescuing exception, System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.HandlerMessageFilter`1.>-Send>d__5.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

The code involved with receiving the response is:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>  
{  
     var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(MqUri), h =>  
      {  
          h.Username(MqUserName);  
          h.Password(MqPassword);  
      });  

   //Start receiving from   
   cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, MqQueueName, e =>  
   {  
       //Handle response from server  
       e.Handler<IResonseToNotificationMessage>(ctx =>  
       {  
        //Forward the response  
          OnResponse?.Invoke(this,new ResponseEventArg()   
                         {ResponseMessage = ctx.Message});  
          return null;  
       });  
   });  
 });
```

I'm using Masstransit v3.2.0. What can cause this error ?

Comment: Posting a code snippet would be helpful, as there is confusion on my part as to which side of the code you are seeing the failure.

Comment: Chris, thanks for your reply. I tried to explain it a bit different. Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

So, the handler has to return a Task, and you're returning `null`. Try this:

```
//Start receiving from   
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, MqQueueName, e =>  
{  
   //Handle response from server  
   e.Handler<IResonseToNotificationMessage>(ctx =>  
   {  
    //Forward the response  
      OnResponse?.Invoke(this,new ResponseEventArg()   
                     {ResponseMessage = ctx.Message});  
      return Task.FromResult(0);;  
   });
```

});